# Dataloader stuck while exporting object

Tags: data-loader, data-export, mac-os-x

I have installed dataloader version 48 in my mac, I too have installed `Zulu Java Sdk`. I am trying to export Account object data from the sandbox and so far I am able to login using `Password Authentication`. However, when after successful login when the list of objects appears and I choose Account or any other object, my dataloader stucks there and in terminal it shows below-mentioned error.

```
INFO  [main] dao.DataAccessObjectFactory getDaoInstance (DataAccessObjectFactory.java:51) - Instantiating data access object: extract.csv of type: csvWrite
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.setScrollWidth(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.setScrollWidth(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.setRedraw(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.extraction.ExtractionSOQLPage.initializeSOQLText(ExtractionSOQLPage.java:487)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.extraction.ExtractionDataSelectionPage.getNextPage(ExtractionDataSelectionPage.java:302)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWizardDialog.nextPressed(LoaderWizardDialog.java:726)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWizardDialog.buttonPressed(LoaderWizardDialog.java:308)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWizardDialog$5.widgetSelected(LoaderWizardDialog.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.uiActions.OperationUIAction.run(OperationUIAction.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
```

[image]

Really,not sure the reason behind it

Comment: I have the exact same issue while running the data loader. It was exporting files fine but all of a sudden it is stuck. I have tried restarting the machine and all but no avail. Also tried your "sudo" command from comments but that didnt work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose Browse, to select the Target for Extraction, and you choose a proper directory, does that help? 
When I launched this on my mac, choosing "Browse" immediately suggested I save the file to my Downloads folder. Could folder access be the issue?

Comment: It an issue related to permission only i tried following command to make it work `sudo java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar dataloader-48.0.0-uber.jar `